# Order column alphanumeric with mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by, concatenation

I can not sort the result as expected, currently I have the following sample records:

```
col_cod  col_title

PI_1      test 1
PI_1.10   ac 004
PI_1.2    ba015
PI_2      ab 010
PI_2.10   ac003
PI_2.3    ea 005
PI_5      aa002
```

I needed the result to show:

```
col_cod  col_title

PI_1      test 1
PI_1.2    ba015
PI_1.10   ac 004
PI_2      ab 010
PI_2.3    ea 005
PI_2.10   ac003
PI_5      aa002
```

Can someone help me ?

Comment: Please add some of the code that you have tried.  I suggest formating the values in the first column exactly the same.  Change "PI_1" to "PI_1.00" and "PI_1.2" to "PI_1.20".  When the text is in the exact same format it will most likely alphabetically sort.  Again, you need to post some code that you have tried and then we'd all love to help.

Comment: Your expectations do not match the data you've posted. `PI_1.2` (which is actually `PI_1.20`) sorts after `PI_1.10`. If you intend `PI_1.2` to be less, then it should have the value  `PI_1.02` instead.